# pynamodb last_evaluated_key always return null

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries, pynamodb

I'm using `Pynamodb` for interacting with `dynamodb`.
However, last_evaluated_key always returns null even if there are multiple items.
When I run this query

```
results = RecruiterProfileModel.profile_index.query(
        hash_key=UserEnum.RECRUITER,
        scan_index_forward=False,
        limit=1,
    )
```

If I try getting this value

```
results.last_evaluated_key
```

it always returns `null`.

However, if I dump the `results` object, it returns

```
{
    "page_iter": {
        "_operation": {},
        "_args": [
            "recruiter"
        ],
        "_kwargs": {
            "range_key_condition": null,
            "filter_condition": null,
            "index_name": "PROFILE_INDEX",
            "exclusive_start_key": {
                "sk": {
                    "S": "PROFILE#6ab0f5bc-7283-4236-9e37-ea746901d19e"
                },
                "user_type": {
                    "S": "recruiter"
                },
                "created_at": {
                    "N": "1677398017.685749"
                },
                "pk": {
                    "S": "RECRUITER#6ab0f5bc-7283-4236-9e37-ea746901d19e"
                }
            },
            "consistent_read": false,
            "scan_index_forward": false,
            "limit": 1,
            "attributes_to_get": null
        },
        "_last_evaluated_key": {
            "sk": {
                "S": "PROFILE#95a4f201-2475-45a7-b096-5167f6a4d639"
            },
            "user_type": {
                "S": "recruiter"
            },
            "created_at": {
                "N": "1677398017.68518"
            },
            "pk": {
                "S": "RECRUITER#95a4f201-2475-45a7-b096-5167f6a4d639"
            }
        },
        "_is_last_page": false,
        "_total_scanned_count": 2,
        "_rate_limiter": null,
        "_settings": {
            "extra_headers": null
        }
    },
    "_map_fn": {},
    "_limit": 0,
    "_total_count": 1,
    "_index": 1,
    "_count": 1,
    "_items": [
        {
            "company_name": {
                "S": "fletcher-rodriguez"
            },
            "created_at": {
                "N": "1677398017.685749"
            },
            "last_name": {
                "S": "craig"
            },
            "first_name": {
                "S": "tyler"
            },
            "designation": {
                "S": "manager"
            },
            "verification_status": {
                "S": "pending"
            },
            "sk": {
                "S": "PROFILE#6ab0f5bc-7283-4236-9e37-ea746901d19e"
            },
            "user_type": {
                "S": "recruiter"
            },
            "email": {
                "S": "fowlerkathy@hernandez.com"
            },
            "pk": {
                "S": "RECRUITER#6ab0f5bc-7283-4236-9e37-ea746901d19e"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can clearly see that `last_evaluated_key` exists over there.
I'm getting confused here.
Please help. I've deadlines to meet. Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
Here is a video attachment of trying to get the value of `last_eveluated_key` in different ways and they all return `null`
[pynamodb last_evaluated_key issue Gdrive video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LbImYQbx4Kz2gGQcFOa0Vz1bJJyhWPuw/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Why do you need `last_evaluated_key` with `limit: 1` and no `last_evaluated_key` in the query? Unless this example is not exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `result` returned by the `query()` is the `ResultIterator` object, which is an iterator.  Its `last_evaluated_key` is the key of the last item you pulled from *the iterator*, not DynamoDB.  Because your code have not yet asked to retrieve any items, the `last_evaluated_key` is not set.

You need to process some or all of the items in the `result`:

```
for item in results:
    print(item)
return results.last_evaluated_key
```

then you will get the key of the last item you processed.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I was able to help!  Could you please mark this answer as a resolution to your question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Pynamo but the key to LastEvaluatedKey looks like `_last_evaluated_key` which is prefixed with `_` have you tried that?

`results._last_evaluated_key`

### Update based on question:

#### Pagination and last evaluated key

The query returns a ResultIterator object that transparently paginates through results. To stop iterating and allow the caller to continue later on, use the last_evaluated_key property of the iterator:

```
def iterate_over_page(last_evaluated_key = None):
    results = TestModel.view_index.query('foo', TestModel.view > 0,
                                         limit=10,
                                         last_evaluated_key=last_evaluated_key)
    for item in results:
       ...
    return results.last_evaluated_key
```

[*Ref*](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/stable/indexes.html)

I believe your issue is that you haven't initiated the query when you're looking for the LastEvaluatedKey. Try print some items first, before trying to obtain the key.

Comment: @lee-hannigan This will return in error

Comment: Even that also returns `null`. Here is the video of me trying that 
[link of video of me trying that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LbImYQbx4Kz2gGQcFOa0Vz1bJJyhWPuw/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Updated my question based on your feedback. I've not used PynamoDB but their docs make it clear you get returned an iterator. Check my answer.

Comment: @LeeHannigan from the manual you quoted, "The `last_evaluated_key` is effectively the key attributes of the last iterated item" meaning that the query has been completed and stored in the iterator.  Please see my response.

Comment: HI, @LeeHannigan thank you very much for the effort. I really appreciate it. The solution by Alex worked actually.

Comment: @LeeHannigan You're correct in your edit. I will leave an upvote.

Comment: If the query had not been initiated, how could `results` possibly print the contents of the DynamoDB record, in your original question?  The answer is misleading @KoushikDas